# Say how to fix the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/core/ApiFutur in fcm server code

Tags: firebase

I am writing code for FCM on server side java. I am getting the following error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.core.ApiFuture" at "           String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);". I tried my level best. If anyone know the solution to make it work Please tell me your idea

```
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Comment: [FCM](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-messaging/17.0.0) does not depend on Google API ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency to your pom should solve it for that particular error:

```
<groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
<artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
<version>1.7.0</version>
```

It can also be downloaded directly from http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/api/api-common/1.7.0/api-common-1.7.0.jar